# How to improve the performance of this query?

Tags: mysql, database-performance

I have following MySQL query and it will take more than `421ms` how can I optimize this?

```
SELECT j.*, c.cl_business_name, c.cl_short_name, 
      m.me_last_name, m.me_first_name, o.co_name, j.jo_deleted_date 
FROM clients c, companies o, jobs j 
LEFT JOIN members m ON j.me_id = m.me_id 
WHERE ? AND j.jo_deleted = ? AND j.co_id = o.co_id AND j.cl_id = c.cl_id 
ORDER BY jo_deleted_date DESC
```

Comment: Do you have indexes created?

Comment: 421ms for a squillion rows ain't bad. Seriously though can you show your table designs and an explain plan.

Comment: 1. Pls provide the full query with ?s substituted. 2. Pls also provide the results of the explain for this query. 3. Also provide the list of indexes with their columns names that you defined on the tables in the query. 4. Are you sure that less than half a sec run time is that bad?

Answer (score -1):

You NEED a condition for your join (by default mysql use inner join) at this position. There is no relation between this companies and clients. Should be something like this: "INNER JOIN companies o ON o.id = c.companiesId".

To speed up your query, join from the biggest in the smaller tables.

I can only guess what the relation looks like, but this query should help you to finish.

I can imagine, this is the reason, for this response time!

```
SELECT 
   j.*, 
   c.cl_business_name, 
   c.cl_short_name, 
   m.me_last_name, 
   m.me_first_name, 
   o.co_name 
   [, j.jo_deleted_date  -> can be ignored, is already in j.* included]
FROM clients c
INNER JOIN jobs j  ON j.cl_id = c.cl_id AND j.jo_deleted = ?
INNER JOIN companies o ON j.co_id = o.co_id   
LEFT JOIN members m ON j.me_id = m.me_id 
WHERE ? 
ORDER BY jo_deleted_date DESC
```

Comment: I agree that explicit join syntax is better than the implicit, however, in terms of query performance there is rarely any difference. When there is a difference, it usually results from not understanding the precedence of explicit join over the comma operator in the from clause. There does not have to be a direct relationship between companies and clients, they are linked through the jobs table.